# Cut text to another line inside joint js element

Tags: jointjs

I am doing a diagram in **jointjs** and I have a rect with a text inside, but that text is so long that does not fit inside the rectangle. How can I cut lines inside it so it all fits at the same size of the rectangle ??

*((escape by itself does not work))*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a utility that joint js has called breaktext, assigning the result to a var :

```
        var wraptext = joint.util.breakText('yourtext|escapejs', {
            width: 300
        });
```

Then, set that var as text attr of the rect:

```
    var rectname = new joint.shapes.custom.Rect({
        size: { width: 680, height: 75 },
        attrs: { 
            text: {
                text: wraptext,
            }
        }
    });
```

Width in this case would be the parameter that determines the long of each text break

Hope it helps !!